# ATL-based COM objects in WinRT/Metro Style App

Tags: c++, com, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, atl

**Scenario:**
I am trying to migrate a C++ application to WinRT/Metro Style. This application uses an ATL/COM object that implements an IDispatch interface by using the class [IDispatchImpl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/494h01te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), however, according to MSDN IDispatchImpl is not available for Metro Style applications.

My ATL/COM class looks like this:

```
class MyATLClass :
    public IDispatchImpl<IMyDispInterface, &IID_IMyDispInterface, &LIBID_MYLIB, 1, 0>, 
    public CComObjectRoot,
    public CComCoClass<MyATLClass,&CLSID_MyATLClass>
{
    ...
}
```

**Question:**
Is there any replacement in WinRT for IDispatchImpl?

The replacement could involve deriving from different classes and discarding my IDL file for example. My ultimate goal is just to be able to do QueryInterface on an instance of MyATLClass and get a reference through IMyDispInterface. I can also include all my files (library and application) in a single project, but I do want to avoid changing the code where IMyDispInterface references are used if possible.

Comment: The subset of COM and winapi that's permitted in a WinRT app is rather small.  It is not just IDpatchImpl, support for IDispatch is completely gone.  And surely a bunch of other winapi calls that your ATL project makes.  You can see a rough overview what's supported by looking in the SDK header files, Windows Kits/8.0/shared subdirectory.  Anything in um is verboten.  Porting such apps to Metro is not typically easy or even possible.

Comment: @ Hans Passant Thanks for your comment. For this specific library, it does not relies too much on Win32, but its features are exposed as a COM interface. I am currently trying to find a way to define this same interface as derived from IUnknown so that I can do QueryInterface on it, but I have not succeeded  so far.

Comment: What are you going to do with your COM object? If it's consumed from C++, you don't need IDispatch. If it's consumed from C#, you should rewrite as either a C++/CX component or as a WRL based component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-implementing my COM/ATL class as a WRL based component is probably the best choice in this scenario (Thanks Larry). More information is provided on these video posts:

[Porting a desktop app to a Metro style app](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Windows-Camp/Developing-Windows-8-Metro-style-apps-in-Cpp/Porting-a-desktop-app-to-a-Metro-style-app)

[The Windows Runtime Library (WRL)](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Windows-Camp/Developing-Windows-8-Metro-style-apps-in-Cpp/The-Windows-Runtime-Library-WRL-)